# python mocking: wrong number of arguments error

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I am trying to use the mock library and basically patching some module functions. So, I have some existing code which looks like this:

```
@patch('loader.utils.run_raise_exception_if_fail')
@patch('time.time', return_value=123)

def test_export_ok(self, _, run_command_mock):
    ....
    calls = run_command_mock.call_args_list
```

This sort of works fine and the test gets called and executed. I am trying to understand what these function arguments mean and where they are generated. I have not used the mocking functionality ever before.

Now, I am trying to mock another function and I added the following patch decorator:

```
@patch('assessment.utils.statistics', return_value={"counts": {'volume': 10, hits=10}})
```

Now, when I try and run this thing, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: test_export_ok() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I am confused as to the patch decorators and these function arguments to the actual test. The function signature for the statistics method looks as follows:

```
def statistics(collisions: np.ndarray,
               obj_size: Union[List, Tuple]):
```

Comment: When you patch some path(s) like that, the method receives the corresponding mocks in reverse order in its parameter signature, that you should adapt accordingly.

Comment: The error is not in the patched function signature but in the test method signature.

Comment: The no. of patch decorators and the no. of variables apart from self in the function should be the same. Try this then "test_export_ok() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given" this error will be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@patch('loader.utils.run_raise_exception_if_fail')
@patch('time.time', return_value=123)

def test_export_ok(self, a, b):
    ....
    calls = run_command_mock.call_args_list
```

For whichever function you are writing the unit test, if there are some 2 inner functions getting called in the main function and u want to patch it. Add the 2 patch decorators with the corresponding return value. Add variables in the main test function "a,b" corresponding to the count of the patch decorators used.

Please try this.

The error for incorrect number of arguments given should be resolved.